# Refactor Node.js Logging Library for Improved Readability

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a Node.js logging library that applies ANSI styling for text formatting. Currently, the code contains some redundancy and could be refactored for better readability. I'm particularly interested in simplifying the method definitions for applying bold and underline styles.

Here's the existing code:

```js
class Logr {
    constructor() {
      this.styles = {
        // ANSI styles for text formatting
        reset: '\x1b[0m',
        bold: '\x1b[1m',
        underline: '\x1b[4m',
      
      };
      this.currentStyles = [];
    }
  
    // Methods to apply different text styles
    
    applyStyle(style) {
      this.currentStyles.push(this.styles[style]);
      return this;
    }
  
    bold() {
      return this.applyStyle('bold');
    }
  
    underline() {
      return this.applyStyle('underline');
    }
  
    // Method to reset styles and generate formatted string
    
    toString() {
      const combinedStyles = this.currentStyles.join('');
      this.currentStyles = [];
      return `${combinedStyles}%s${this.styles.reset}`;
    }
  
    // Method to log messages with applied styles
    
    log(message) {
      console.log(this.toString(), message);
    }
  }
  const logr = new Logr();
  logr
  .underline()
  .bold()
  .log("An underlined message with a bold text.");
```

I'm considering refactoring it to improve readability and maintainability. I want to ensure that the library remains flexible and easy to use, especially when applying bold and underline styles.

Expectation: Both logr.underline.bold("Message") and logr.bold.underline("Message") should be functional after refactoring.

Comment: The code looks good to me. You're aware that ANSI styling isn't part of [the console specs](https://console.spec.whatwg.org)? For now it only seems to work in Chrome. An [issue about this](https://github.com/whatwg/console/issues/197) has been opened in 2021, but it is still open. Don't expect much progress on this soon.

Comment: Actually, the question is not about compatibility. I want to refactor the code for better readability. currently I need to write logr.underline().bold().log("Message") but my expectation is different (mentioned above)